# Debezium, partitions assigment using primary key

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

I'm new with debezium and I can't find information about sending messages from database to kafka with specific keys. It is possible to configure debzium to send messages with special key based on one of primary keys? Can I achive this using debezium transforms or some regex?

Answer (score 0):

There is a topic routing SMT as per this [documentation page](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/topic-routing.html) which does a little bit more than just changing Kafka record key. I will still suggest to be careful because Kafka partitioning guarantees event ordering within the partition. Changing it can break the ordering guarantee Debezium provides.